# Storyboard lock view as device

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I encounter a problem with Xcode storyboard.
It does not allow me to `View as` different devices. When I click on one device shown in the image below, Xcode displays a lock icon in the middle of the screen.

How can I solve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock icon appears when an object in the storyboard has the "lock" in the "identity inspector" set.
In your case probably you have locked one of the viewControllers and you can't change the simulated size of the view because you can't set any property of the object locked.
If the storyboard is too big search in the source for the three types of lock.

Comment: I found one view that is locked to all properties.